# Reference an object, based on a variable with it's name in it

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm looking for a way to reference an object, based on a variable with it's name in it.
I know I can do this for properties and sub properties:

```
var req = {body: {jobID: 12}};
console.log(req.body.jobID);             //12

var subProperty = "jobID";
console.log(req.body[subProperty ]);     //12

var property = "body";
console.log(req[property][subProperty]); //12
```

is it possible for the object itself?

```
var req = {body: {jobID: 12}};
var object = "req";
var property = "body";
var subProperty = "jobID";
console.log([object][property][subProperty]); //12

or

console.log(this[object][property][subProperty]); //12
```

Note: I'm doing this in node.js not a browser.

Here is an exert from the function:

```
        if(action.render){
            res.render(action.render,renderData);

        }else if(action.redirect){
            if(action.redirect.args){
                var args = action.redirect.args;
                res.redirect(action.redirect.path+req[args[0]][args[1]]);

            }else{
                res.redirect(action.redirect.path);
            }
        }
```

I could work around it by changing it to this, but I was looking for something more dynamic.

```
        if(action.render){
            res.render(action.render,renderData);

        }else if(action.redirect){
            if(action.redirect.args){
                var args = action.redirect.args;
                    if(args[0]==="req"){
                        res.redirect(action.redirect.path+req[args[1]][args[2]]);
                    }else if(args[0]==="rows"){
                        rows.redirect(action.redirect.path+rows[args[1]][args[2]]);
                    }
            }else{
                res.redirect(action.redirect.path);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Nop, and this definitely looks like an XY problem. Imagine the consequences of this, like PHPs `$$var`, ugh. And `window[object]` is not a solution, as somebody might suggest that. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Haters gonna hate: `eval(object + '.' + property + '.' + subProperty)`

Comment: @Johan That's the answer. Why not put it in answers?

Comment: Bugger, I'm writing a web application and sometimes I need to redirect to another page. E.g. after they finish editing a job I redirect them to the view job page. The thing is when redirected they normally need some kind of ID, typically this comes from req.body or req.params, so I have an object that keeps track of the properties/sub properties. But for pages that create new jobs it needs to come from rows.insertid

Comment: @z5h I would like him to answer enclanrs' question, since it's most likely an XY problem, as mentioned.

Comment: @JamesG: Try posting a simplified real-world example.

Comment: @elclanrs why window[object] is not solution ?

Comment: @z5h He was afraid [Douglas Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) might come and downvote it. 
@JamesG : Yes, please post an example, I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. If you make a redirection, req.body/req.params values should be kept, shouldn't they ? Or you can create a GET parameter when redirecting (eg. `res.redirect("/goThere?id=58")`)

Comment: I've updated the question to include an excerpt from the function and a possible workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally it's impossible to reference an object by its name. But since you have only two possible candidates...

```
var args, redirect_path = '';
if(args = action.redirect.args) {
    try {
        redirect_path = ({req:req,rows:rows})[args[0]][args[1]][args[2]];
    } catch (_error) {}
}
res.redirect(action.redirect.path + (redirect_path || ''));
```

I'm using inline object `{req:req,rows:rows}` as a dictionary to lookup for `args[0]` value.

I wrapped the whole construction with `try ... catch`, because it's dangerous. For example, passing anything except `'req'` or `'rows'` as `args[0]` will result in an exception being thrown.

I also moved `res.redirect` outside of `if` to clarify the code.

## Update

It's also possible to use `args` array with arbitrary length. But to do so you'll need to loop through `args` array:

```
var branch, redirect_path;
if (action.redirect.args) {
  try {
    branch = { req: req, rows: rows }
    action.redirect.args.forEach(function(key) {
      branch = branch[key];
    });
    if ('string' === typeof branch) {
      redirect_path = branch;
    }
  } catch (_error) {}
}
res.redirect(action.redirect.path + (redirect_path || ''));
```

A added `'string' === typeof branch` check to ensure that the resulting value is a string.

Comment: Nice, I like that, have you got an easy way to adapt it so that it could cope with the length of args varying? Alternately is there some way to put in a blank/null/undefined third arg?

eg req.body.jobID but rows.insertID